# Can not sign a profile with Xcode after using qmake

Tags: swift, qt, qmake

I am using QtCreator and I created an app following those steps ("https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qt-creator-accelbubble-example.html") and it works fine in the simulator but to use it on my iPhone I have to install it through xCode, there is a way with QtCreater where I use the command qmake in the Terminal and it will create a .xcodeproj file but when I try to run it on my iPhone or sign it to my AppleId I get those two errors.

1. An invalid value 'XC com qt_dev bubbleGame18at07' was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.
2. No profiles for 'com.qt_dev.bubbleGame18at07' were found
   Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.qt_dev.bubbleGame18at07'

Comment: As the error message said, you need to create a development-profile for your apple developer account, which includes the appID, which you must also request from apple, using their appstoreconnect website. QtCreator will be able to find all the profiles and certificates required once you created, downloaded and imported them. My recommendation: use XCode for this.

Comment: Try to create a “hello world” app in Xcode with the same app ID, if you can build and deploy that, chances are high that it will work in Creator, too. Xcode might do some initial steps automatically (like downloading provisioning profiles) that Creator doesn’t. Also make sure you have the right development team selected inside Qt Creator’s project build settings.

Comment: My AppleId is working with other projects that are created within xCode but using QtCreater to build a project and then imported to xCode using the command "qmake", will get me those two errors when I try to sign it up with a developer account.